# Error logging in after resetting admin password

Tags: sitecore-client, membership-provider

I reset the Sitecore Admin password from SQL using the below query:

```
UPDATE 
    [aspnet_Membership] 
SET 
    [Password]='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=', 
    [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==', 
    [IsApproved] = '1', 
    [IsLockedOut] = '0'
WHERE 
    UserId IN (
        SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin'
    )
```

But now I'm geting this `error: invalid length for a base-64 char array or string`,  when I am trying to login.

This is Sitecore 9.

Comment: The SQL you have posted there works when i tried it. Try copying into notepad and then into SQL Management studio to make sure you didn't copy any special hidden chars into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently switch your hashing algorithm to SHA512? If so, you'll need a different password value:

```
USE [sitecorecmsSitecore_Core];

UPDATE 
    [aspnet_Membership] 
SET 
    [Password]='K8N8GUW8UiNT2mPdjvuBDH+QmvA3R61M9buVvCwFHwtDjpMzTxs34lg0uQ0azCITqh6FkUZlX4kM72lsAyuyXQ==', 
    [PasswordSalt]='p5B6HOWKt0ctMZaSNXTlfw==', 
    [IsApproved] = '1', 
    [IsLockedOut] = '0'
WHERE 
    UserId IN (
        SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\admin'
    );
```

Answer (score -4):

UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership

SET [Password]='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=', [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==',
[IsApproved] = '1', [IsLockedOut] = '0'
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')

This worked properly for me.

Comment: You have just posted the same SQL as in the original question.